# Clearing the terminal in vs code without using ctrl C

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I want to know how do I clear up my terminal in Vs code without using Ctrl C
and restarting my how program?

Comment: If no script is running you can type `clear` to clear terminal screen

Answer (score 0):

There is an unbound command:

`workbench.action.terminal.clear`

that will do what you want without terminating any running tasks/processes.  You can set it to a keybinding of your choice if you search for it in the `Keyboard Shortcuts`.  It appears to work when you have **editor focus** and **not** terminal focus.